# Akka readJournalPluginId for inmem journal plugin

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

Which `readJournalPluginId` should I use with inmem journal plugin?

```
"akka.persistence.journal.plugin" -> "akka.persistence.journal.inmem"

PersistenceQuery(system).readJournalFor[???](???)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use this dependency:

```
"com.github.dnvriend" %% "akka-persistence-inmemory" % "1.2.11"
```

the one from this package:

`akka.persistence.inmemory.query.journal.scaladsl._`

Basically:

```
PersistenceQuery(system).readJournalFor[InMemoryReadJournal](InMemoryReadJournal.Identifier)
```

Comment: I'm using the builtin one.

Answer (score 0):

For the built-in in memory journal plugin, the plugin ID you should use is:

```
akka.persistence.journal.inmem
```

This is essentially they key that the plugin code uses to look up configurations necessary to spin things up, take a look @ https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-persistence/src/main/resources/reference.conf